# display:inline-block not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have two div in the page: one in the left called "menu", the other in the right called "content", and there're two children inside the left div.

html:

```
<div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      menu1
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      menu2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
  border-style:solid;
}

.menu{
  display:inline-block;
}

.content{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

(jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ds81vtrp/2/)

I need to align the "menu" div and the "content" div horizontally, so I use display: inline-block, but the result is wierd that the "content" div is placed at the right of the bottom children(i.e. the "menu2" div), not the parent(i.e. the "menu" div), why?

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: Put your css, pls

Comment: You should change your styling technique to something reliable like `flexbox` or `css-grid`. `Float` or `inline-block` are terrible for creating complex layouts.

Comment: Perhaps your css may contain a rule that does not allow you to fulfill `inline-block`. Therefore, you need to provide your css for full understanding. The more information you give, the faster and more correct you will get the correct answer.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov so sorry that I missed it.

Comment: @realjin, Thanks for adding the css. You can solve your problem by adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.content`. Use the first solution to @HaoWu.

Comment: @tacoshy Yes, I'm new to vanilla css(I use frameworks before and write little css tyles myself), I know flex works, I just want to know the mechanism and detail of inline-block, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign them [`vertical-align: top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```css
.container {
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.container > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      menu1
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      menu2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And FYI, it's a better practice to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here since you can get rid of the annoying whitespace between inline blocks, and also align them freely such as making the content occupy the rest of the space horizontally:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.container > * {
  border: solid 2px blue;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      menu1
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      menu2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **vertical-align**

`The vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment of an element.`

and you may need: top

```
top– Align the top of the element and its descendants with the top of
the entire line.
```

**vertical-align: top;**